# band range with every day dates

Tags: jquery, html

I was trying to get all the dates

i.e

Every day dates in a band range with year selecting. I came across below code but it is not up to my requirement. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance. My code so far which i got from jquery blog is.

```js
$( function() {
    $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
      range: true,
      min: 0,
      max: 500,
      values: [ 75, 300 ],
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
      }
    });
    $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
      " - $" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<p>
  <label for="amount">Price range:</label>
  <input type="text" id="amount" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
</p>
 
<div id="slider-range"></div>
```